# Dropdown menu flowing off screen

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with my dropdown menu (see image below) and that it overflows off of the screen when the icon is clicked. I'm not sure if this anything to do with its parent elements that are hidden - the dropdown menu only appears when the screen size is below 1000px. Once the screen is below 1000px, the `inline-block` of `li's` are hidden.

[image: see image]

The HTML and CSS

```css
#navbar {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5%;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 5px;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 70px;
  padding-top: 38px;
  position: relative;
}

nav a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#dropdown {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-nav {
  display: none;
}

nav li {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {

#dropdown {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown-nav {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  float: left;
}
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <h3 id="logo">Rob Moore LTD</h3>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="nav" href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav" href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav" href="#services">Services</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav" href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <ul id="dropdown">
    <li>
      <p><i class="fas fa-hamburger fa-2x"></i></p>
      <ul class="dropdown-nav">
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```